# Making text and Image appear side by side and change size based on device

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create my own personal website. I want to do two things:

1. Make a picture appear on the left hand side of the page and some text on the right side.
2. Resize the image and text based on devices.

Here is the code I am using (using):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row">
 <div class="indexbox">
   <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
     <img class="img-responsive img-border img-left" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/17/Bugs_Bunny.svg/300px-Bugs_Bunny.svg.png" height="190" width="142" alt="">
     </img>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-lg-8 col-md-8">
     <p class="visible-xs">
       <p> Hi I'm XXXXXXX, a PhD Candidate in XXXX at XXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXX. <br /> <br /> 
                  Before joining the YYYYYYYY PhD program at YYYYYYYY, I received a BA in YYYYYYYY from YYYYYYYY, YYYYYYYY and a MS in YYYYYYYY Economics from YYYYYYYY, YYYYYYYY. My research broadly focuses on YYYYYYYY.  
       </p>
     </p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I cannot seem get the desired result. I think that the two codes here: `col-xs-7 col-sm-6 col-lg-8 col-md-8` and `img-responsive img-border img-left` should be able to achieve the result but it does not seem to work all the time. Could someone help me out a little bit here?

P.S. I am testing the code out here:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.1.1

Comment: The structure you are using for your html seems wrong. Can you fix it? eg. `<class>` tag. Should it be a `<p>` or `<div>`?

Comment: I changed it. It should be p. Please let me know if this looks correct now. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Just follow the instructions on the bootstrap web page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/. It'd also help if your HTML wasn't a mess. Why have you got a `<p>` inside another `<p>` for no reason? You don't close your row and where is the container? Why do your columns have multiple size classes?

Comment: Like I said I am not familiar with html coding at all. The only reason I am learning this is to create my own website. Thanks for pointing out the mistakes. I will fix them in the final version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/16e7qkn8/11/

```
<tr class="row" style="display:inline-block;">
```

and

Img :   `style=" width: 100%;height: auto;"`

You can use Tables and css like this

Answer (score 1):

Try out this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/17/Bugs_Bunny.svg/300px-Bugs_Bunny.svg.png" height="190" width="142" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-8">
    <p class="visible-xs">
      <p> Hi I'm XXXXXXX, a PhD Candidate in XXXX at XXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXX. <br />
        <br /> Before joining the YYYYYYYY PhD program at YYYYYYYY, I received a BA in YYYYYYYY from YYYYYYYY, YYYYYYYY and a MS in YYYYYYYY Economics from YYYYYYYY, YYYYYYYY. My research broadly focuses on YYYYYYYY.
      </p>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I loved the outline box in your code. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

maybe your Bootstrap is not connected well. 
Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-responsive img-border img-left" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/17/Bugs_Bunny.svg/300px-Bugs_Bunny.svg.png" height="190" width="142" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
   <p> Hi I'm XXXXXXX, a PhD Candidate in XXXX at XXXXX, XXXXXXXXXXX. <br /> 
<br /> 
                Before joining the YYYYYYYY PhD program at YYYYYYYY, I received a BA in YYYYYYYY from YYYYYYYY, YYYYYYYY and a MS in YYYYYYYY Economics from YYYYYYYY, YYYYYYYY. My research broadly focuses on YYYYYYYY.  
    </p>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Worked like a charm. I was able to also figure out which parts of my code were causing the issue from your answer.